# How to change X-axis datetime value jan-01 to Oct-01 using .net chart control

Tags: c#, .net

I am trying to show x axis value in the form of date(MMM-yy) but it is always begin with jan-01. So please provide solution to display other then jan-01, I mean instead of Jan-01 show oct-01.

Please find the simulated function :

```
    private static void drawGraph()
    {
        List<GraphPoints> listGP = new List<GraphPoints>();
        listGP.Add(new GraphPoints()
        {
            RecordDate = "01/10/1984",
            benchmark = "10000.00"
        });

        listGP.Add(new GraphPoints()
        {
            RecordDate = "29/06/1987",
            benchmark = "30396.00"
        });

        listGP.Add(new GraphPoints()
        {
            RecordDate = "31/05/1989",
            benchmark = "10000.00"
        });

        listGP.Add(new GraphPoints()
        {
            RecordDate = "30/09/1993",
            benchmark = "310137.88"
        });

        listGP.Add(new GraphPoints()
        {
            RecordDate = "31/12/2015",
            benchmark = "440037.28"
        });


        Graph.Chart chart;

        chart = new Graph.Chart();
        chart.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(10, 10);
        chart.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(800, 300);

        chart.ChartAreas.Add("draw");

        chart.ChartAreas["draw"].AxisX.IntervalType = Graph.DateTimeIntervalType.Years;
        chart.ChartAreas["draw"].AxisX.LabelStyle.Format = "MMM-yyyy";
        chart.ChartAreas["draw"].AxisX.MajorGrid.LineColor = Color.Black;
        chart.ChartAreas["draw"].AxisX.MajorGrid.LineDashStyle = Graph.ChartDashStyle.NotSet;

        chart.ChartAreas["draw"].AxisY.IntervalAutoMode = Graph.IntervalAutoMode.VariableCount;
        chart.ChartAreas["draw"].AxisY.MajorGrid.LineColor = Color.Black;
        chart.ChartAreas["draw"].AxisY.MajorGrid.LineDashStyle = Graph.ChartDashStyle.NotSet;

        chart.ChartAreas["draw"].BackColor = Color.White;



        chart.Series.Add("Bench-Mark");         
        chart.Series["Bench-Mark"].XValueType = Graph.ChartValueType.Date;
        chart.Series["Bench-Mark"].ChartType = Graph.SeriesChartType.Line;            
        chart.Series["Bench-Mark"].Color = Color.Red;
        chart.Series["Bench-Mark"].BorderWidth = 1;

        foreach (var item in listGP)
        {
            chart.Series["Bench-Mark"].Points.AddXY(Convert.ToDateTime(item.RecordDate).ToOADate(), item.benchmark);
        }

        chart.SaveImage("MyImage.jpg", Graph.ChartImageFormat.Jpeg);
    }
```

[image]

See Graph axis points are showing from jan 1988.

Comment: Try setting `chart.ChartAreas["draw"].AxisX.LabelStyle.IntervalType = DateTimeIntervalType.Months;`

Comment: No Change in graph.Its same as i mentioned in above.

Answer (score 0):

There is a nice page on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456628.aspx) on various types of labels.

It explains three types of labelling:

- Using the Label of the `AxisX.LabelStyle.Format` and `Axis.Interval` property to create a regular grid of labels not really connected to the data points
- Using the  `DataPoint.AxisLabel` property to label each `DataPoint` individually
- Using  `CustomLabels` to set labels at arbitrary points on an axis.

You are using the first option but this will put a `Label` at the beginning of one unit of the `AxisX.IntervalType` which in your case will be years even if you switch to `Months` because there simply are too few points.

This really should be simple to correct; since you do not want the `IntervalType` units labelled but the individual `DataPoints`, you should add `AxisLabels` to each `DataPoint` and all ought to be well:

```
Series S1 = chart.Series["Bench-Mark"];
foreach (var item in listGP)
{
    DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(item);
    int p = S1.Points.AddXY(dt, listGP[item]);
    string l = dt.ToString("MMM-yyyy");
    S1.Points[p].AxisLabel = l;
}
```

Unfortunately with your data, the `Chart` control's built-in 'intelligence' makes this a bit harder; the issue is that no matter which combination of `Interval` and `IntervalType` you choose it just never will show **each** `AxisLabel`. In fact I only managed to display those that actually hit the `Interval`, i.e. `DataPoints` the fall the 1st of a month. But your data are randomly spread out over several years.

**But** you can use `CustomLabels` as a workaround. After adding the `AxisLabels` in the code above call this little helper function to add  `CustomLabels`; we need to tell the `Chart` for which range each is to be displayed, and with a **large enough** range they all show up where they should  (according to **my** data):

```
void addCustomLabels(Chart chart)
{
    Series S1 = chart.Series[0];
    ChartArea CA = chart.ChartAreas[0];
    CA.AxisX.CustomLabels.Clear();
    for (int i = 0; i < S1.Points.Count; i++)
    {
        CustomLabel cl = new CustomLabel();
        cl.FromPosition = S1.Points[i].XValue - 10;  // 10 day back and ahead..
        cl.ToPosition = S1.Points[i].XValue + 10;   //..will be enough space for one label
        cl.Text = S1.Points[i].AxisLabel;
        CA.AxisX.CustomLabels.Add(cl);
    }
}
```

[image]

Note that such a solution will only work well if your data points are as **sparse** as in the example; for many points the labels would **clutter** the axis.